# Laravel session id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Всем привет. Как получить данные сессии Laravel по её id? Метод хранение сессий в файле. А так же, как отправить файлы cookie с помощью js ? Нужно для идентификации пользователя на сокете.
id сесси получаю вот таким образом:

```
$ss_id = $request->cookie(Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session');
```

Comment: `\Session::getHandler()->read($sessionId)`
получить сессию по ее id

Comment: `$request->session()->get('key')` а так уже не работает? или  не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев
В том то и прикол, что это сокет Workerman. Я туда не передаю, или не знаю как передать объект запроса. Пока что единственным решением придумал такой код: $session = (new SessionManager(App::getInstance()))->driver(); $session->setId($ss_id); $session->start();

Comment: Единственное что осталось - посылать куки сессии при подключении.